# I migrated all my micro services to arm64 arc but auto scaling is not working properly

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

How can I setup cluster auto scaler for eks arc node group?

I want to setup cluster auto scaler for arm64 arc

I tried below image I got on google but not working

please help me and let me know if something is possible in this for auto scaling

```
Containers:
   cluster-autoscaler:
    Image:      k8s.gcr.io/autoscaling/cluster-autoscaler-arm64:v1.20.0
    Port:       <none>
    Host Port:  <none>
    Command:
      ./cluster-autoscaler
      --v=4
      --stderrthreshold=info
      --cloud-provider=aws
      --skip-nodes-with-local-storage=false
      --expander=least-waste
      --node-group-auto-discovery=asg:tag=k8s.io/cluster-autoscaler/enabled,k8s.io/cluster-autoscaler/test-devo
      --balance-similar-node-groups
      --skip-nodes-with-system-pods=false
```

Comment: "k8s.gcr.io Image Registry Will Be Frozen From the 3rd of April 2023"
https://kubernetes.io/blog/2023/02/06/k8s-gcr-io-freeze-announcement/

Try `registry.k8s.io/autoscaling/cluster-autoscaler-arm64:v1.20.0` instead

Otherwise, please tell us what is not working. What exactly is the problem?
First, check the events of the autoscaler pod "kubectl -n YOURNAMESPACE describe pod AUTOSCALER_PODNAME" (see below under "events")

Otherwise check the pod logs `kubectl -n YOURNAMESPACE logs AUTOSCALER_PODNAME` 

I need more information of your problem.